# Get standard out from command line call in c#?

Tags: c#, batch-file, process, stdout, streamreader

Right now I am trying to get the standard out when I pass in the command to a batch shell (.bat file) through C#. I am able to get the initial standard out when the cmd prompt starts up (says something like "Hello World" when opened), however if I give it an argument like "ping 127.0.0.1", I am unable to get the output. I have tried two ways of capturing the output so far. The starting of the process stays the same.

```
private void testShell(string command)
{
    ProcessStartInfo pi = ProcessStartInfo(*batch shell path*, command);
    pi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    pi.UseShellExecute = false;
    pi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    pi.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    Process pr = Process.Start(pi);
//option 1
    while(!pr.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        //do something with the line
    }
//option 2
    string str = "";
    using (System.IO.StreamReader output = pr.StandardOutput)
    {
        str = output.ReadToEnd();
    }
//option 3
    string output = pr.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    //do something with the output
}
```

Is it possible to pass in a argument to a batch file (this seems to be the actual problem)?

Comment: So `*batch shell path*` is pointing to a `.bat` file, or to `cmd.exe`? I pointed it to a `.bat` file that runs `ping 127.0.0.1` and I see the output with option #3 just fine (using `Console.Write(output)`).

Comment: Batch shell, not the default windows cmd.exe.

Comment: What is "Batch shell"? Are you pointing it to a `.exe`, or to a `.bat` file?

Comment: I call it a shell, meant  .bat file.

Comment: Reading your post again, I think your issue is that you want to execute arbitrary commands through `command`, yes? If your `.bat` file has `ping 127.0.0.1` in it then you do not need to pass in any arguments at all, just pass in the `.bat` file to `ProcessStartInfo` and it happens to start it correctly. Otherwise, use Xiaoy312's solution but replace `*batch shell path*` with `@"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"`. By calling cmd.exe directly with the `/c ` argument you can have it execute commands.

Comment: The batch file has specific commands that cannot be called in the default cmd.exe, this is why I am using it.

Comment: `command` in your code is an argument and batch files do not execute arguments passed to them; there may be a way to have it do so, but by default an argument is just available to the batch file through `%1` for the first argument and so on. If you want your `.bat` file to execute `ping 127.0.0.1` then it has to be saved in to the file itself; passing it in as an argument to the file does not execute it. I would have to see the `.bat` file itself to determine why you are not getting output; I don't think it's due to your code because it works fine for me and looks just like the MSDN example.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a method to the outputdatareceived event.

```
 pi.OutputDataReceived += (objectsender,DataReceivedEventArgs  e) => datareceivedtwritetolog(sender, e);
```

Then create a method to do something with the output:

```
 public static void datareceivedtwritetolog(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
     string logpath = @"c:\log-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyy") + ".txt";
     File.AppendAllText(logpath, e.Data + Environment.NewLine);
 }
```

Comment: Not seeing any output (just trying to print out e.Data).

Comment: You need to start the proccess before it. Then place: pi.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); and pi.WaitForExit(); after

Comment: I set up the start info like above, and then start it with Process.Start. I then set up OutputDataReceived on that process, with calling ReadToEnd() and WaitForExit() after. Still not seeing any output.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly pass a command as an argument.

```
CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
```

You need to write the start argument as `/c ping 127.0.0.1` or :

```
ProcessStartInfo pi = ProcessStartInfo(*batch shell path *, "/c " + command);
```

note: this will break, if the start process file is a batch file (*.bat) instead of a shell console ("cmd")

---

Alternatively, you can write the command to the standard input :

```
pr.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
// do stuffs with pr.StandardOutput
```

Comment: It is a batch file, not cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're showing won't compile (it's missing a `new` directive).  At any rate, something specific about the batch file you're not showing is probably failing.  The following will work:

Create a file called `Example.cs` with the following contents:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Example
{
    class ExampleClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo("ExampleBatch.cmd", "a b c d");
            pi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            pi.UseShellExecute = false;
            pi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pi.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            Process pr = Process.Start(pi);
            string output = pr.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("[" + output.ToUpper() + "]");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a file called `ExampleBatch.cmd` with the following contents:

```
@echo off
echo This is from the example.
echo Param 1: [%1]
echo Param 2: [%2]
echo Param 3: [%3]
echo Param 4: [%4]
echo Param 5: [%5]
```

Then compile the .cs file with `csc Example.cs`.  And finally, running `Example.exe` will show the following output:

```
--------------------
[THIS IS FROM THE EXAMPLE.
PARAM 1: [A]
PARAM 2: [B]
PARAM 3: [C]
PARAM 4: [D]
PARAM 5: []
]
--------------------
```

This shows that the batch file was able to capture the command line arguments, and the C# program was able to capture the output and process it.